# How to make the dropdown menu closer to the dropdown icon and how to make the outer color white to black?

Tags: html

The dropdown-menu is not close to the drowpdown icon. Putting a margin doesn't help.
And how to make the outer color white to black?

```css
.dropdown-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 90%;
  top: -50px;
  background-color: black;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0;
  background-color: black;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu li {
  background-color: black;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-menu ul {
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars white"></i>
                </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">BLOG</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-search" title="fafa"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

[image: navbar]

Comment: You haven't included enough code in your question to replicate the issue. Please edit your question to include all of the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can see the problem - if you haven't included the code that is causing the issue, we can't tell you how to fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, try inline style, not advisable tho, but you can create a custom class on `dropdown-menu` and copy my inline style and target, also add `important` to the styles so it would **override** the default bootstrap style,and your question looks a little confusing in the sense that from the code snippet ran below it shows a different thing from the snapshot you shared, but I think I understand what you mean.

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars white"></i>
                            </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:100px;position:absolute;margin-top:-20px;padding-top:20px;"> //adjust this until it fits your taste 
    <li><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">SERVICES</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">BLOG</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-search" title="fafa"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

and for the color inspect element from your browser,

[image: Inspect element]

find the div from the style and element column in the inspector and change `border-top` to black like this `<div style="border-top:1px solid #000;"></div>` from your code on code editor. Happy coding.

Comment: Don't use inline styles! You even say yourself its not advisable, so why would you suggest that someone does it?

Comment: Also, don't tell people to upvote you (especially just because you are new).